# Creating SEO canonical paths (none absolute)

Tags: php, html, seo, canonical-link

I am using my code like this to generate a canonical link for SEO purposes

```
<link rel="http://www.mydomain.com$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]">
```

So lets say the file I go to is http://www.mydomain.com/thisfolder/?this=that&yes=no

The canonical link will display as

http://www.mydomain.com/thisfolder/?this=that&yes=no

What I want is no matter what the extra variables being passed in the URL are that it will display the canonical as

http://www.mydomain.com/thisfolder/

I have tried both REQUEST_URI and SCRIPT_NAME in my $_SERVER[]; but both do the same thing. Is there a way I can achieve this whether I am just not using the correct name to $_SERVER[]; or is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For instance, if the current script was accessed via the URL http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar, then $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] would contain /some/stuff.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php